# Any IDE supporting SBT?

Tags: scala, plugins, ide, sbt

is any IDE supporting SBT in a proper way (like Maven for example)? Because I've found a lot of tools that *generate IDE-related configuration files* but I haven't found any plugins that give any support of SBT interaction form within IDE.

I want to make an IDE-agnostic project based on SBT, but also I want to be able to use full spectrum of features that IDE provide and not just use it as an editor and do all the other stuff from console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does [Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) fit the bill ? It has an [SBT plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pluginId=5007) (and a Scala plugin, obviously!)

Comment: From all that I've seen it's probably the best. But when you compare it with the Maven support... Well you know.

Comment: The SBT plugin is no longer relevant, it is integrated into [IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/). The unfortunate thing is that this "feature" is very "magical". Things happen (or don't). You have no way of knowing. After using it for a month, I've had more headache than ease-of-use. I think I'll just switch to command line, or try the Typesafe Activator web editor - it can't be more frustrating... can it?

Answer (score 8):

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but putting it here as a work-around for working with SBT in eclipse for whoever is interested.

SBT generates eclipse config files, but after you import it, it works fine from within eclipse. You just need to set up the project for the first time outside of Eclipse, run SBT to resolve dependencies, generate eclipse structure using the eclipse sbt plugin and import into Eclipse. After that, you can run the code directly from Eclipse and it works fine.

Here're the steps in detail:

1. Create the folder structure as follows:
   [image: ScalaSBTProject]
2. Create a file called `plugins.sbt` in the `project` folder and add the following line to it:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
   ```
3. Create `build.sbt` in the root directory i.e. `ScalaSBTProject` with content similar to the following. I'm using akka here, but add and remove libraries as you require:

   ```
   name := "ScalaSBTProject"

   version := "1.0"

   scalaVersion := "2.10.0-RC2"

   resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

   libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-cluster-experimental_2.10.0-RC2" % "2.1.0-RC2"
   ```
4. Open command prompt and run `sbt` in the directory `ScalaSBTProject`. SBT will download and resolve whatever dependencies are required
5. Run the command `eclipse` at the SBT command line. This will generate all the eclipse related project files
6. Import `ScalaSBTProject` into Eclipse using `File->Import->Existing Project` to workspace, and make sure you check `Import into workspace`

EDIT: Just as a Post-Script, you can quite easily create a batch file to take the name of the project and generate the eclipse compatible project, just a way to speed up the process.

Comment: yes, you're right. But I'm looking for a plugin that will tell IDE that libs are on the remote repository and ext. The way you're telling about is more like a workaround on how to use Eclipse with a project that's using an SBT while I'm searching for GUI tools for SBT

Comment: Yes, I know this probably isn't what you're looking for, hence the disclaimer at the very beginning. I had a tough time to get even this to work, so figured it couldn't hurt posting it here if it helped even a bit